# Creating a list of evenly divisible numbers with a different divider on each iteration of a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, modulus

first question on stackOverflow :) ! 
I would like to divide the range list by a different divider on each iteration of the for loop:
For that I thought about having `x` change on each iteration. I tried different things like making `x` a list,and multiple other improvised ways, but to no avail. I have no idea why the code seems to iterate correctly but the value of `x` doesn't change with `x -= 1`.
The ultimate goal is to compare those lists and find similar evenly divisible numbers. But one thing at a time...

Here is the code:

```
def divisible(x):
    lst1 = []
    while x >= 2:
        for each in range(0, 100001, 20):
            if each % x == 0:
                lst1.append(each)
        x -= 1
        return lst1



print(divisible(19))
```

It prints the first value of `x` only:

```
[0, 380, 760, 1140, 1520, 1900, 2280, 2660, 3040, 3420, 3800, 4180, 4560, 4940...etc]
```

Comment: Well asked for a first question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your return statement is inside the while loop, which means that your function returns after the first iteration; preventing more iterations. Making this small modification results in this code:

```
def divisible(x):
    lst1 = []
    while x >= 2:
        for each in range(0, 100001, 20):
            if each % x == 0:
                lst1.append(each)
        x -= 1
    return lst1



print(divisible(19))
```

Comment: Indeed . Thank you.